# PHP CLI : OS turns out of memory while memory_get_usage() returns 40MB memory use

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks, debian

When running my PHP CLI script, my OS turns out of memory while memory_get_usage() returns 40MB memory use.

Here is a sample of what this script performs.

```
<?php
$aInstances = array();
$aInstances = myClass::getInstances(); // returns ~ 1500 objects in array()

while ( count($aInstances) ) {

  $instance = array_pop($aInstances);

  // do some stuff - memory usage increases
  $instance->loadFromDb();
  ......

  // free memory
  unset($instance);
  gc_collect_cycles(); // force garbage collector cleanup (memory usage grows up to 110MB otherwise)
}

// Display Php Memory Usage
echo number_format(memory_get_usage());
// returns 40,320,200
echo number_format(memory_get_peak_usage());
// returns 41,002,056

// Display Php System Memory Usage
echo memory_get_usage(true);
// returns 41,943,040
echo memory_get_peak_usage(true)
// returns 41,943,040
?>
```

This script seems to do his job, but **when i try to see system memory usage by another way** (like a `ps aux` on another shell), **memory usage is more than 90%**.

Script was killed by system one time because it was out of memory.

Some more information :

- OS : Debian 6, 2GB memory
- PHP version : 5.3.3-7
- php.ini (cli) memory_limit = 128M

Do you have any ideas to explain and / or resolve my problem ?

Many thanks...

Comment: Do you mean that the memory usage of the PHP script was showing 90% of the available system memory from `ps`? Or that it was 90% usage across all processes?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, the script uses **90% of system available memory**, system kills it when memory use increases near 100%.

Comment: That sounds very wrong. Also, it seems wrong that the system killed the script when it ran out of physical memory - I'm assuming you have swap space? It should use that. You might have found a bug in PHP CLI.